# Android onResume() called before onPause()?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a major doubt in the lifecycle of Android Activity.In normal English terms Resume will be done once u have done the Pause.But in the lifecycle of Activity OnResume has been called even before the onPause at the very first time alone.What's the reason behind this?

Can anybody tell me why it's been structured like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the activity life cycle and identify that onPause() and onResume() concept for android is different. I am only answering to below question.. Rest you can read

> Can anybody tell me why it's been structured like this?

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

> **onResume()**
>
> Called when the activity will start interacting with the user. At this
>   point your activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user
>   input going to it. Always followed by onPause().

It means if you want to start something (say a timer which shows the second count when this activity is in focus and receiving user interaction), you can start it in onResume(). It is onResume() is our callback when this activity is in focus. **It should be called whether or not this activity is just created, or resumed after a pause**.

> ya after onStart() its fine,but in english terms resume will be termed
>   after pause right? Why it has been designed in such a way any reason
>   for that?

I think you should not take the literal meaning in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In General English terms, Resume means when something starts interacting again after it was paused,

> but in Android terms, it means when an Activity is at the foreground and when the user starts giving input to the activity. It could be at foreground for the first time or even after it was paused. onResume() is just to imply that User have started interaction with the activity.

`onStart()` and `onResume()` are two different terms. `onStart()` is called when the Activity is becoming visible to the user. and `onResume()` is called when the activity comes to foreground and user starts interacting with it.

I will give you an example,

Suppose you have an activity with some Moving Objects, here I will describe the operations performed during different stages,

`onStart()-` Here the activity starts, not the Animation.

`onResume()-` Here the objects starts Animating.

`onPause()-` Here the objects stops Animation, Activity is still running.

`OnStop-` Here the Activity stops.

Hope it helps in some understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this image:

[image: Activity lifecycle]

onResume() will be called just after onStart(). I think what you have notices is that onResume(). [This](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Activity_Lifecycle) has described activity lifecycle in detail:

OnResume:
This method is called when the activity will start interacting with the user after being in a pause state. **When this method is called, the activity is moving to the top of the activity stack, and it is receiving user input**. Activities can override this method if they need to perform any tasks after the activity begins accepting user input.

Comment: ya after onStart() its fine,but in english terms resume will be termed after pause right? Why it has been designed in such a way any reason for that?